# WScript.Echo throwing object required error in vbscript

Tags: command-line, vbscript, wsh

I'm trying to display messages as my vbscript program runs. It runs off a command prompt in xp, for example: cscript.exe test.vbs.  I don't want to use msgBox while this is running as I just want it to post the scripts progress, but I don't want any user interaction.

I tried using Wscript.echo "Some text", but I'm getting compile errors when I step through the program using Words built-in vbeditor.

I found this code and it runs fine in another file:

```
Option Explicit
Dim strComputer
strComputer = "LocalHost"
WScript.Echo "Computer: " _
& strComputer
WScript.Quit
```

I then tried using Dim and set to setup a Wscript variable, but that didn't work either.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? I did verify Wscript is running on this machine.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word uses VBA (Visual Basic for Applications), not VBScript. Although both languages belong to the Visual Basic family, they have differences. One of them is that the `WScript` object isn't available in VBA - that's why you're getting errors when debugging your script in Word.

Having said that, your code is valid and runs perfectly fine with both `cscript` and `wscript`.

Comment: You are correct! That explained it and everything works fine. Thank you!